# How to do a distinct over two columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
>>> df
     0   1   2    3  4  5
  0  1   2   3  1.0  A  B
  1  2   5   6  1.0  A  B
  2  1   7   8  NaN  C  A
  3  2  10  11  1.0  B  B
```

I want to count the number of times unique values comes for each value in column 0 with respect to two columns - 4 and 5. For example, in the above case the output would be something like this

```
     0   1   
  0  1   3   
  1  2   2
```

Because for value 1 in column 0 the number of unique values in col 4 and 5 are A,B,C while for value 2 only A,B.

Answer (score 3):

You can `groupby` column 0, flatten the values from column 4 and 5 and then count the number of unique values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.groupby("0")[['4', '5']].apply(lambda g: len(np.unique(g.values.flatten())))


#0
#1    3
#2    2
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: I have a rather large dataframe. For most of the rows this one is giving Nan.  I think I should mention the columns 4 and 5 in the above example should have numerical values to exactly replicate the DF, but I don't think it will matter. Will it?    Also, I checked for both columns 4 and 5, none of them have any Nan values. (checked using df ['4'].isnull().values.any())

Answer (score 2):

Melt your dataframe to get `'0'` as the index like column and `['4', '5']` as the value column. Then groupby `'0'` and count the unique values of the resulting `value` series:

```
pd.melt(df, '0', ['4', '5']).groupby('0').value.nunique()
Out[69]: 
0
1    3
2    2
```

Answer (score 0):

***To get the unique values in selected columns from a data frame***

```
import pandas as pd

df2=pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,2,4], 'b':[1,1,1,2,2], 'c':'abc','def','abc','efg','hij']})

df2 = df[['b', 'c']].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['b', 'c'])

print(df2)
```